# HyperLinks Not Recognized in Java App for only one of many users

Tags: java, windows, swing, hyperlink

This is a strange problem and I could use some help figuring out what to do. I have a Java swing application that contains hyperlinks. I have dozens of users for which these links work just fine. However, I have a new user that cannot get the links to be recognized. That is when he hovers the mouse over one it does not change to a finger nor does clicking it do anything. Since this is the only user that has this problem I have to believe there is a setting somewhere that prevents links from working. He is using Windows 7 and Java 8. I cannot seem to find anything in the JRE settings that addresses this nor can I see anything in his AV software or OS settings either. Does anyone have any idea what setting and where might cause this behavior? TIA.

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a virus or a hijacked browser to me.

Comment: When you say Java application - do you mean a webapp? or a Java Swing application or what?

Comment: A Java  swing application. I take it then that you don't think it is a setting somewhere?